# What's the most elegant way to load and switch between property sources in Spring 5.1.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'd like to load and switch property sources at run time to read different property values but with same property keys in an application.

The Property files looks like:

A.properties

```
key1=ValueA1
key2=ValueA2
```

B.properties

```
key1=ValueB1
key2=ValueB2
```

According to their [official document](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-using-propertysource)

I solves my issue with the follow:

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:MessageMappingA.properties", encoding = "UTF-8", name = "A")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:MessageMappingB.properties", encoding = "UTF-8", name = "B")
```

and

```
@Autowired
Environment env;

@Autowired
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;

public void setA() {
    ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().get("A"));
    }

public void setB() {
    ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().get("B"));
    }
```

This seems ugly, and I doubt if it is really necessary to store these property sources in a List and use addFirst() to reorder them so as to set the highest precedence of the sources. Wouldn't it better to load-as-I-use a .properties file? Any Suggestions?

Comment: You can try creating a `profile` for each of the `application.properties` file and while creating the `jar` you can specify which `profile` to use and spring will use the respective `application.properties` files you have configured in the `pom.xml`.

Comment: When do you call setA & setB? I assume it is at runtime somewhere in the program?

Comment: @ Rentius2407 Yes, I build those method for runtime, to switch between those .properties files.

Comment: Just to be clear, you require the property to be switched when the application is running - is that right?  Because `profile` setting happens right before container initialization and it will not fit this case.

Comment: @ring bearer Exactly, I don't think profile setting is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation.

> The search performed is hierarchical...
>   By default, system properties have precedence over environment variables

To override the loaded property, you have to set the property you want to use at the highest precedence. To do that according to the spec is to call the `propertySources.addFirst(new MyPropertySource());` method with the propertySouce.

Now back to your example.

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:MessageMappingA.properties", encoding = "UTF-8", name = "A")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:MessageMappingB.properties", encoding = "UTF-8", name = "B")
```

The above code will load property B last, which means that the properties in B will be loaded if they have the same key.

MessageMappingA.properties

```
currency=R
```

MessageMappingB.properties

```
currency=$
```

When injecting `@Value("${currency}")`, MessageMappingB will take precedence and the value will be $.
If you want to inject/override with MessageMappingA's properties you have to load it into the property source of the environment at the highest priority.

```
public void setA() throws IOException {
    EncodedResource encodedResource = new EncodedResource(new ClassPathResource("MessageMappingA.properties"));
    ResourcePropertySource resourcePropertySource = new ResourcePropertySource(encodedResource);

    MutablePropertySources propertySources = this.environment.getPropertySources();
    propertySources.addFirst(resourcePropertySource);
}
```

or

```
public void setA() {
    this.environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(this.environment.getPropertySources().get("A"));
}
```

But there is a catch.

The default scope of a bean is singleton. The property of MessageMappingA.properties will not be injected into the bean that is of type `@Scope("singleton")` because once the bean is initialized the MessageMappingB property is injected.
You need to make sure that the bean that wants to use the new property value, injects it every time it is called. Even if you make the bean `@Scope("prototype")` it might not work, because the upstream bean that is calling it might be of `@Scope("singleton")`.

I would recommend using `environment.getProperty(key)` instead of `@Value("${the.key}")` to get the property value, when different property sources are loaded at runtime to override properties.